# How do I modify the embed code on a Cognito Form to prefill form data

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to embed a Cognito Form on my site and prefill with data from the querystring.  Is the following example the right way to do this?

[image: the embed code you provided]

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Generally, this example is correct.  Embedded forms may be prefilled by adding "entry" to the JSON specified when loading a form.  This JSON should reflect the structure of the form.  You can see what this JSON will look like by using http://requestb.in/ and configuring your form to post data to a URL from this service.

If you need assistance with a specific form, support troubleshooting the JavaScript, etc., please submit a [Bug Report](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/) so we can assist you directly.

Comment: The resolution for this was to add `.split(",")` after retrieving the querystring values as the fields being prefilled were lists of checkboxes, thus were actually arrays of strings, not just strings.